# CreateProcessAsUser doesn't work when "change user"

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, windows-7

First , I want to thank all the persons who works for this site, very useful for a developer. This is the first I am blocked in my developement since 3 days. I have searched solutions on Internet  but I find nothing which solves this issue.

So, I develop a service which have to execute an external program on vista/seven/xp when a user is logged. Some characteristics of this service :

- automatic
- no interactive.
- detect the session ID of the user logged

To run the external GUI application as the interactive user:

1. To be sure a user session is opened, I list ALL the "explorer.exe" process, extract their Pid and SessionID with the msdn function ProcessIdToSessionId
2. if the SessionID of the logged user is equal with the session ID of this "explorer.exe" process, I am sure that the "good" desktop is running so now I can execute the external program. (I say "good" desktop because, as you know, more than one user session can be opened on the system )
3. after that, I run the application with this function:

   ```
   function RunInteractive(prog_filename: String; sessionID: Cardinal): boolean;
   var hToken: THandle;
   si: _STARTUPINFOA;
   pi: _PROCESS_INFORMATION;
   begin
   ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
   si.cb := SizeOf(si);
   SI.lpDesktop := nil;
   if WTSQueryUserToken(sessionID, hToken)
   then  begin
         if CreateProcessAsUser(hToken, nil, PChar(prog_filename), nil, nil, False, 0, nil, PChar(ExtractFilePath(prog_filename)), si, pi)
         then  result := true
         else result := false;
       end
   else  Begin
         result := false;
         End;
   CloseHandle(hToken);
   end;
   ```

This code is ok in most of case except one: when I change User. Let me explain it with 2 simple users (Domain\user1 and Domain\user2):

1. To be clean, I install the service and reboot the system
2. I open session with user1: the external program is executed and I can see its form
3. I **close the session**  and opensession with user2 : the external program is executed and I can see its the form.

If I do this X times, the result is always the same, very good...but If I do this:

1. I re-install the service and reboot the system
2. I open session with user1: the external program is executed and I can see its form
3. this time, I am **not close the session**  but **change user** with user2 : the external program is executed but I cannot see the form and an error is occured : System error code 5: Access denied.

Something is wrong but I don't find the solution. Thanks for your answers...

Comment: "Dismiss all the persons" probably isn't what you mean to say - it means to ignore them or send them away! Maybe "applaud" or "thank"?  We know what you mean, anyway, just thought you might be interested :)

Comment: Excellent! I only use google translate only for this word ("remercier" in french). You can check it, google returns: thank,  dismiss and render thanks. I never trust it anymore

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to enumerate running explorer.exe processes, you can use `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId()` instead, and then pass that SessionId to `WTSQueryUserToken()`.  Note that `WTSQueryUserToken()` returns an impersonation token but `CreateProcessAsUser()` needs a primary token, so use `DuplicateTokenEx()` for that conversion.

You should also use `CreateEnvironmentBlock()` so the spawned process has a proper environment that is suited to the user account that is being used.

Lastly, set the `STARTUPINFO.lpDesktop` field to `'WinSta0\Default'` instead of `nil` so the spawned UI can be made visible correctly.

I have been using this approach for several years now and have not had any problems with it.  For example:

```
function CreateEnvironmentBlock(var lpEnvironment: Pointer; hToken: THandle; bInherit: BOOL): BOOL; stdcall; external 'userenv.dll'
function DestroyEnvironmentBlock(lpEnvironment: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall; external 'userenv.dll';

function RunInteractive(prog_filename: String): Boolean;
var
  hUserToken, hToken: THandle;
  si: _STARTUPINFOA;
  pi: _PROCESS_INFORMATION;
  SessionId: DWORD;
  Env: Pointer;
begin
  Result := False;

  ZeroMemory(@si, SizeOf(si));
  si.cb := SizeOf(si);
  si.lpDesktop := 'WinSta0\Default';

  SessionId := WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId;
  if SessionId = $FFFFFFFF then Exit;

  if not WTSQueryUserToken(SessionID, hToken) then Exit;
  try
    if not DuplicateTokenEx(hToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, nil, SecurityIdentification, TokenPrimary, hUserToken) then Exit;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hToken);
  end;

  try
    if not CreateEnvironmentBlock(Env, hUserToken, False) then Exit;
    try
      Result := CreateProcessAsUser(hUserToken, nil, PChar(prog_filename), nil, nil, False, CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT, Env, PChar(ExtractFilePath(prog_filename)), si, pi);
      if Result then
      begin
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
      end;
    finally
      DestroyEnvironmentBlock(Env);
    end;
  finally
    CloseHandle(hUserToken);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank U Remy for your excellent explanations.The issue is not resolved but your answer help me.I compile the service with your code: the issue is the same in fast user switching. So I decide to run another external program like notepad.exe: no problem! After that,I tried to simply run the external program with a batch file:"ACCESS DENIED".SO I conclude that the issue isn't in the source code of the service but in the source code of the external program that only behaves badly in "fast user switching".I'm going to see that and back to you if I found the solution.But maybe you have an idea...

Comment: I forget to say that after the error dialog message " Code 5, access denied" , a second  error dialog  appears with this message : "Cannot change Visible on OnShow or OnHide". Other thing: my "write_log" functions included in the method FormCreate of the main form don't seem to work

Comment: The user account you are using to spawn the program likely does not have permissions to the log file you are trying to write to.  Remember that by default, a file is owned by the user account that creates it, unless the file is stored in a folder that has lesser restrictions applied.  To share access to a file by multiple users, either store the file in a subfolder of %ALLUSERSPROFILE%, and/or use `SetFileSecurity()` to adjust the file's SACL/DACL to allow access to all users.

Comment: The log filename is : %appdata%\applicationame\logfilenameYYMMDD.log... and is created during the method FormCreate. %appdata% is an alias of C:\Users\user1\AppData\Roaming so there is one log for one user. But I am sure that it is a security problem as you say.

Comment: okay, i found the culprit, guilty of the Message dialogError "ACCESS DENIED" : One function of the jcl library (GetInteractiveUserName) which is inside the method FormCreate of the external program. I am very surprise...I read the code but I cannot tell u now why it raised this error only in "fast user switching"...If you are interested, you can see the code in jclSecurity.pas. 
@MarcusAdams

Comment: %appdata% is user-specific. User1 cannot access user2's files, and vice versa. Use %commonappdata% for sharing.

Comment: I badly explain before...I don't want to sharing the log file, I prefer 1 log file for 1 user ==> no acces problem when 2 users want to access their log file.
As I said before, the JCL function GetInteractiveUsername is guilty. I don't know why. I am going to replace this function by using the jclFucntion GetEnvironmentVar('USERDomain',userDomain) and GetEnvironmentVar('USERNAME',username). 
A BIG THANKS to you...

Comment: If the app needs the username of the account that is running it, then why not just use the Win32 API `GetUserName()` function instead?

Comment: You can use `LookupAccountName()` to get the domain.

Comment: @remy: WtsQeuryUserToken a,ready returns a primary token so there's no need to duplicate it. I also advise to Impersonate so you have access to his/her files and you might also consider to load the user profile.

Comment: I see your point about impersonation, but loading the user profile should not be necessary as this code is meant to load the new process within a user account that is already logged in.  If the calling app were logging in the user account anew via `LogonUser()` or `CreateProcessWithLogonW()` instead, then it would make sense to load the user profile manually.

Comment: It is a good habit to call WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId several times with a delay because the session may not be established yet.

Comment: In addition CPAUW may alter the CommandLine String (parameter is actually an in/out). So it must not point to a literal string (in this example).
For security reason the filename should be enclosed in quotation marks, otherwise spaces in the path could lead to incorrect behaviour; especially with parameters. If you just want to run an app consider using parameter lpApplicationName instead.
As remko pointed out, CPAU should be called using an impersonated token. Otherwise the executable file is access using the current process token(SYSTEM). See remarks in MSDN of CPAU. A mandatory read.

Comment: @remy: if you do not load the profile, the reference count (to the profile) will not be increased which means windows may have troubles when the user logs out and you still have some registry keys opened.

Comment: In my case, my service just wants to run an .exe in a current interactive session (to display a rich UI message to the user) and then forget about it.  One problem with loading the profile manually is that you have to wait for the new process to terminate and then unload the profile manually. That is not an option in my case as I may need to run the .exe many many times (ie, last night alone it was run thousands of times during an automated test), and it is not guaranteed that they will terminate quickly (and multiple processes could be running in parallel).

Answer (score 0):

Probably your method of getting the session ID by finding the "good" explorer.exe is not working for fast user switching.

Try having your application register for Session change notifications with [WTSRegisterSessionNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You will then get notifications when the session switches, complete with the current session ID.

Note the following:

> To receive session change notifications from a service, use the
>   [HandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Comment: The sessionID is good, I log this value in a file and I compare it with the session Id of the process in the taskmanager. This is the same value. For notification, I already use this function and use  WTS_SESSION_LOGON for condition on execution of the external program.

Comment: Tanks Marcus for your answer but The sessionID is good, I log this value in a file and I compare it with the session Id of the process in the taskmanager. This is the same value.